# Riak Java Client failed to compile

Tags: java, riak

I'm working with riak. Trying to access it from Java. Here is the code:

```
package eee.xxx;

import com.basho.riak.client.IRiakClient;
import com.basho.riak.client.RiakException;
import com.basho.riak.client.RiakFactory;
import com.basho.riak.client.bucket.Bucket;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws RiakException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RiakException {
        IRiakClient myClient = RiakFactory.httpClient("127.0.0.1");
        Bucket myBucket = myClient.fetchBucket("Pacan").execute(); 
    }

}
```

And after compiling, it throws such the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at com.basho.riak.client.raw.http.HTTPClientAdapter.<init>(HTTPClientAdapter.java:85)
    at com.basho.riak.client.RiakFactory.httpClient(RiakFactory.java:144)
    at eee.xxx.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 3 more
```

I have no idea how to solve this. Please, help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Riak](http://docs.basho.com/) has a number of 3<sup>rd</sup> party library dependencies, one of which is the standard JSON library which you appear to be missing. It needs to be available on the classpath at compile & runtime. It can be found [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar).

As there about 8 dependencies it is easier to let [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) manage this for you by adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.basho.riak</groupId>
    <artifactId>riak-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it worked for me :) but I have new onew exception :)  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost

Comment: This is another dependent jar that you're missing `httpclient`. Go to the [Maven Riak Page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.basho.riak/riak-client/1.0.6) and click on the _artifact_ you're missing then download the `binary` you're missing.